# Apache Jena - Internal Ping Timeout does not work

Tags: java, sparql, ping, jena

Many public SPARQL Endpoint Services owe a Ping Timeout of 30 seconds. This is way too long for my program as I want to have it around 10 seconds.

There is a function in Apache Jena for an internal Ping Timeout, but apparently it doesn't work as I tested with some queries which take way longer than 10 seconds. I tried **many variations** with my code below. If someone posts similar lines of code, please test if it **really works**. I appreciate any help.

Also another question: Would the internal Ping Timeout from Apache Jena also work if the SPARQL Endpoint Service is down? It would be really helpful to throw an Exception as the user in my program won't have to desperately wait for an answer.

Java Code snip:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public static ResultSet executeQuery(String queryString, String service) {
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    QueryEngineHTTP queryEngine = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(service, query);
    queryEngine.setTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ResultSet resultSet = queryEngine.execSelect();
    return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: There are two types of timeout supported by `QueryEngineHTTP`, readTimeout`` and `connectTimeout`. In your case you just set the `readTimeout` You can set both if you use `setTimeout(long timeout1,                 TimeUnit timeUnit1,  timeout2,  timeUnit2)` . From the documentation: *"Set timeouts on the query execution; the first timeout refers to time to first result, the second refers to overall query execution after the first result. Processing will be aborted if a timeout expires. Not all query execution systems support timeouts."* `QueryEngineHttp` does only support connection timeout

Comment: You would need some extra Thread for having a hard timeout on read. The connection timeout, on the other hand, is handled by the APahace HTTP Request API, where it states *"Client tries to connect to the server. This denotes the time elapsed before the connection established or Server responded to connection request."* This is implemented but won't "fire" in your case I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout from the remote service is under the control of the remote service.  They may provide endpoint-specific ways to set the timeout (see their documentation). Jena has no other control of the remote execution for a query timeout on the server.